# Numpy array commands within plotting pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, matplotlib

I am printing subplots with pandas dataframes and numpy. This code prints 4 graphs per page, then saves the plots as separate pdfs.

Could I call the numpy array in a order to plot dataframe2 in a more efficient manner? Maybe with the enumerate command?

I have attached a picture of the graphs I am outputting.

My code gets the job done, however, I feel like it is is very inefficient in general. For my own learning I would like to simplify the code.

[Pandas_Outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3CB9.png)

```
no_of_graphs = 2*2

for a in range(2):

    start = 1  + counter * no_of_graphs 
    end = 4 + counter * no_of_graphs

    ax = df1[df1.columns[start:end]].plot(figsize=(12,15), grid = True, legend = True, subplots=True, layout = (2,2), sharex = False, color = 'blue')

    df2[df2.columns[1 + counter * no_of_graphs]].plot(ax=ax[0][0], grid = True, legend = True, linestyle = 'dashdot', color = 'red')
    df2[df2.columns[2 + counter * no_of_graphs]].plot(ax=ax[0][1], grid = True, legend = True, linestyle = 'dashdot', color = 'red')
    df2[df2.columns[3 + counter * no_of_graphs]].plot(ax=ax[1][0], grid = True, legend = True, linestyle = 'dashdot', color = 'red')
    df2[df2.columns[4 + counter * no_of_graphs]].plot(ax=ax[1][1], grid = True, legend = True, linestyle = 'dashdot', color = 'red')

    ax = np.squeeze(ax)
    fname = 'file' + str(a) + '.PDF'

    for y in range(0,2):
        for x in range(0,2):
            ax[x,y].set_xticks(df1.index[::60])
            ax[x,y].set_xticklabels(df1.Time[::60], rotation=270)
            plt.tight_layout()
            plt.gcf()
            plt.savefig(fname, dpi = 1000)

    counter +=1 
    print(counter)
```

Comment: what is `a` and `counter` anyway?

Comment: A is the number of pages.

Comment: The counter is function I used to control how many datafames are plotted.

Comment: `plt.tight_layout()` and `plt.savefig` should be outside the loops over x and y, such that they are only called once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand fully your question, but you certainly can be more efficient to plot your second dataframe.

```
axs = df1.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2), color = 'blue');
axs = df2.plot(subplots=True, layout=(2,2), ax=axs, linestyle = 'dashdot', color = 'red')
```

[image: output]